# Can't find reason for error 500 - Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm new to Perl and its use in CGI. I've been having this error 500 for some hours and still don't know where's the error(s). The script is placed in the corresponding `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` folder of the Apache server. It's then called by this simple HTML form:

```
<FORM action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/sensors.cgi" method="POST">
Sample period: <input type="text" name="sample_period">  <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</FORM>
```

As fas as I know, an error 500 appears when there was an improper upload or a bug in the script. But I've tested uploading other files and had no problems with it. Thats why I believe there may be a bug in the code. This is the Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Handle;

# Open the output file that contains the sensors' readings. It's open in write mode, and
# empties the content of the file on each opening.
open (my $readings, ">", "sensors_outputs.txt") || die "Couldn't open the output file.\n";


# Defines the physical magnitudes and sets each one a random value.
my $temp = rand 30;
my $hum = rand 100;
my $pres = 1000 + rand(1010 - 1000);
my $speed = rand 100;

for(;;) {
    # Writes in the file-handler's file the values of the physical magnitudes.
    print $readings "$temp\n$hum\n$pres\n$speed";
    # Flush the object so as not to open and close the file each time a new set of
    # values is generated.
    $readings->autoflush;
    # Move the file-handler to the beggining of the file.
    seek($readings, 0, SEEK_SET);
    # Generate new a new data set.
    $temp = rand 10;
    $hum = rand 100;
    $pres = 1000 + rand 10;
    $speed = rand 100;
    sleep 1;
}
close $readings || die "$readings: $!";
```

Don't hesitate to ask me for more context if needed. Thanks in advance

Comment: The Perl community has largely moved away from CGI and on to [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) these days.

Comment: [use strict, use warnings](http://perlmaven.com/always-use-strict-and-use-warnings)

Comment: @Quentin: "moved away from CGI" is one thing, but not everyone is moving to just one framework...

Comment: @stevieb — 18 frameworks listed on the page I linked to.

Comment: @Quentin: my apologies; the link text is just a bit misleading; I should have followed through. ++

Comment: Plack/PSGI is not a framework. Plack/PSGI is a specification and a toolkit that underlie most modern Perl web frameworks.

Comment: `close ... || die` will not do what you mean. Use `close ... or die` or `close(...) || die`

Comment: @oals, thanks for pointing that out. What does it do? I thought it was raising an exception if the file could not be closed.

Comment: The precedence is wrong. The `die` won't be executed on a failed `close()`. It will be executed only on an un-defined `$readings` (which shouldn't happen with your script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem there is that the script doesn't output an HTTP response, which the CGI specification requires.

At a minimum you would need something like:

```
print "Status: 204 No Content", "\n\n";
```

but it would be more usual to say

```
print "Status: 200 OK", "\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain", "\n\n";
print "Success!";
```

That said, `500` just means there there is an error. It might be related to the code. It might be related to the server configuration. The above is the obvious problem, but there might be other issues. When you get a 500 error you **need** to look at the server's error log and see what the error message actually says. There is no point in trying to solve the problem before you do that.

Comment: The error 500 was solved by adding what you stated. It's my first time with Apache and never used the logs before, but now I know how. Thanks for pointing it out.